# Unable to expand on 'yes/no' list field

Tags: 2013, list, rest

I have 2 lists, `List1` and `List2`.

`List1` is a list of items which has an ID lookup to items in `List2`

I have a query which queries an item in `List1` and then returns expanded values from the associated id in `List2`

My query looks like this:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items?$expand=List2&$select=ID,List2/ID,List2/URL,List2/Title
```

And that has been working fine. Up until I added a `Yes/No` field to `List2`, and tried to get that expanded value.

Now with my new query:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items?$expand=List2&$select=ID,List2/ID,List2/URL,List2/Title,List2/YesNoField
```

I get the error

> The query to field 'List2/YesNoField' is not valid.

It appears that the Rest API call is not happy expanding on a boolean type column.

Is there any way to make this work, or any suggested work arounds?

Comment: If expand have the same limitations as ProjectedFields, boolean is not valid. A possible workaround used then is adding a calculated field with the value of your boolean field, and project to that. Maybe that works for expand too

Comment: Didnt think of that workaround, and it works wonders for me (expanding on the new 'YesNoFieldResult' calculated to text column). :) Thanks Anders!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based off Anders suggestion, I ended up adding a second column field which is a 'text returning' calculated field off my boolean field (as it is not apparently supported for expanding on).

This allowed me to get the value on expansion in my query.